# Mimosa csslint configuration not being picked up from csslintrc file

Tags: node.js, build, mimosa

I have created a .csslintrc file in my Mimosa project as documented in mimosa-config-documented.coffee

I have also created a .jshintrc file

The css lint file IS NOT being picked up
The JS hint file IS being picked up

This is confirmed when I run ... mimosa watch -sD (debug mode)

Changing CSS lint rules in mimosa-config-documented.coffee doesn't work either

Does anyone know how to adjust CSS lint rules for Mimosa? I find the mimosa-csslint module great but some of the rules are overly restrictive and i need to turn some off

If anyone can help it would be amazing - thanks
No skeleton projects seem to cover this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things:

1) Mimosa's CSSLinting doesn't support a .csslintrc file.  Would be a feature request on the mimosa-csslint module.  You can see in the docs: http://mimosa.io/configuration.html#lint that jshint includes a property to point at the jshintrc file, but there is no such property for csslint.

2) If you are updating properties in the `-documented` file, you are doing it in the wrong file.  That file is merely for documentation.  `mimosa-config.js` is where you want to be making changes.